# Ring as a sum of an ideal and its annihilator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ a finitely generated ideal of $A$. If for any maximal ideal $m$, the localization $I_{(m)}$ is either $0$ or $A_{(m)}$ , then $$I + \operatorname{Ann}(I) = A$$

and  $I$ is generated by an idempotent element.

What I have so far is that $I_{(m)} = 0$ if and only if $\operatorname{Ann}(I)\nsubseteq m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $A$ is commutative.

It suffices to prove $(I + \mathrm{Ann}(I))_{\mathfrak{m}} = A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. The left hand side is $I_{\mathfrak{m}} + \mathrm{Ann}(I)_{\mathfrak{m}}$. Since by assumption $I_{\mathfrak{m}} \in \{0,A_{\mathfrak{m}}\}$, we may assume $I_{\mathfrak{m}}=0$ and need to prove $\mathrm{Ann}(I)_{\mathfrak{m}}=A_{\mathfrak{m}}$.

More generally, assume $S^{-1} M = 0$ for a finitely generated $A$-module $M$, where $S \subseteq A$ is a submonoid. Choose a finite generating set and for every generator $m \in M$ choose some $s \in S$ with $sm = 0$. By taking the product of all $s$, we find some $s \in S$ with $s M = 0$. Thus, $s \in \mathrm{Ann}(M)$ and hence $S^{-1} \mathrm{Ann}(M) = S^{-1} A$.

For the second claim: Write $1 = i + s$ with $i \in I$ and $s \in \mathrm{Ann}(I)$. Multiplying this equation with $i$ yields $i = i^2$. Multiplying it with any element of $I$ shows $I = \langle i \rangle$.